# How to get contract's code owner

Tags: ink, smart-contract

Can the information about the owner of the actual contract code blob (the account that deployed the code) be accessed from the contract environment?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get the owner of the actual contract without adding specific logic for ownership inside your contract.
But you can still get this info at `pallet-contract` level with the event `contracts.Instantiated` that will provide you AccountId of the deployer & AccountId of the contract.

To add ownership logic to your contract, have a look at [OpenBrush](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts/tree/main/contracts/src/access)

Full list of functions exposed by ink! & usable in your contract [here](https://docs.rs/ink_env/latest/ink_env/#functions)

Comment: This would only help you to store the owner of the contract but not of the blob itself. Can I ask what you need this information for in a contract?

Comment: To impose the restriction that only the code owner can create instances of the contract without hardcoding account names